# How to freeze GridView header?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, controls

As in a title, does anyone know how to freeze GridView header in ASP.NET ?

Comment: You can check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130564/i-need-my-html-tables-body-to-scroll-and-its-head-to-stay-put) question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option (a) buy into a UI package that includes a souped-up GridView with this functionality built-in.

Option (b) roll your own - it's not simple. Dino Esposito [has one approach](http://weblogs.asp.net/despos/archive/2003/12/12/43091.aspx).

EDIT: Just noticed that the Dino article links to a subscriber-only area on the ASPnetPro magazine site.

Here's [another approach](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2007/07/31/freeze-asp-net-gridview-headers-by-creating-client-side-extenders.aspx) using extenders.

Comment: How to freeze if the header is consist of a main header and number of sub headers?

Comment: @bonCodigo - you'll probably get better responses to your question if you post it as a separate question. In this case you're likely not using an ASP.NET GridView, right?

Comment: I have gridviews in the web application. Due to maintaining server side responses, we just have to stick to gridview. The biggest challenge is the sub headers. Worst case, we plan to put the headers in an html and hide the headers from gridview. But then, I have a bad feeling that DML/CRUD will not perform well.

Answer (score 4):

You can do it in the css

**Freeze Header:**
1. Define class .Freezing in Stylesheet:

```
.Freezing
{
   position:relative ;
   top:expression(this.offsetParent.scrollTop);
   z-index: 10;
}
```

2.Assign Datagrid Header's cssClass to Freezing

Comment: But it seems to work only under IE and not under FF :( Anyway, thanks! :)

Comment: More specifically, expressions don't work in IE8 Standards mode.

Answer (score 2):

Try this open-source project for ASP.NET. It extends GridView to provide fixed header, footer and pager and resizable column width. Works well in IE 6/7/8, Firefox 3.0/3.5, Chrome and Safari.

http://johnsobrepena.blogspot.com/2009/09/extending-aspnet-gridview-for-fixed.html

Answer (score 2):

I too faced a similar issue while developing in the web applications in Asp.Net 2.0 / 3.5.

One fine day, I came across **IdeaSparks ASP.NET CoolControls**. It helps to display fix column headers, footer and pager.

I used them personally and I really loved it!

[To check the control click here : IdeaSparks ASP.NET CoolControls](http://ideasparks.codeplex.com/releases/view/40091)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I think I have solution of this.
please see below javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    var orgTop = 0;
    $(document).scroll(function () {
        var id = $("tr:.header").get(0);
        var offset = $(id).offset();
        var elPosition = $(id).position();
        var elWidth = $(id).width();
        var elHeight = $(id).height();
        if (orgTop == 0) {
            orgTop = elPosition.top;
        }
        if ($(window).scrollTop() <= orgTop) {
            id.style.position = 'relative';
            id.style.top = 'auto';
            id.style.width = 'auto';
            id.style.height = 'auto';
        }
        else {
            id.style.position = 'absolute';
            id.style.top = $(window).scrollTop() + 'px';
            id.style.width = elWidth + 'px';
            id.style.height = elHeight + 'px';

        }
    });
</script>
```

where `.header` is the css class of your Grid header.

Just add this script on the page and replace `header` with the css class name you have used for your header.

Answer (score 1):

Give this  a try should solve the problem 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/FreezePaneDatagrid.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following sample

[Freeze GridView Columns](http://www.vbknowledgebase.com/?Id=91&Desc=Freeze-GridView-Columns-and-Headers-in-ASP.Net-CSS)

Answer (score 0):

```
        <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" >
            $(document).ready(function () {
                var gridHeader = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').clone(true); // Here Clone Copy of Gridview with style
                $(gridHeader).find("tr:gt(0)").remove(); // Here remove all rows except first row (header row)
                $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%> tr th').each(function (i) {
                    // Here Set Width of each th from gridview to new table(clone table) th 
                    $("th:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")", gridHeader).css('width', ($(this).width()).toString() + "px");
                });
                $("#GHead").append(gridHeader);
                $('#GHead').css('position', 'absolute');
                $('#GHead').css('top', $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').offset().top);
        
            });
        </script>
    




            <h3>Scrollable Gridview with fixed header in ASP.NET</h3>
            <br />
            <div style="width:550px;">
                <div id="GHead"></div> 
                <%-- This GHead is added for Store Gridview Header  --%>
                <div style="height:300px; overflow:auto">
                    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" 
                        CellPadding="5" HeaderStyle-BackColor="#f3f3f3">
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="ID" DataField="StateID" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Country" DataField="Country" />
                            <asp:BoundField HeaderText="StateName" DataField="StateName" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
                </div>
            </div>
```