# Fixed Header Gridview with scrollable body in asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I  have a grid-view placed inside a div and scroll bar is there. I want to set the grid view header fixed and while scrolling only the content will be scrollable.
How can do this....
Thanks in Advance....

Comment: I think someone has asked this already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157528/how-to-freeze-gridview-header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in C# after gridview bind
GVBrand.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;

add follwoing css in gridview

```
    table {
        width: 100%;
    }

    thead, tbody, tr, td, th { display: block; }

    tr:after {
        content: ' ';
        display: block;
        visibility: hidden;
        clear: both;
    }

    thead th {
        height: 30px;

        /*text-align: left;*/
    }

    tbody {
        height: 120px;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    thead {
        /* fallback */
    }


    tbody td, thead th {
        width: 19.2%;
        float: left;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/T9Bhm/7/

Answer (score 1):

Try doing the following.

Hide the header
Configure the div, so you have the side bar
Add on top of the div another div, with the column names

Don't forget to fix the column sizes and have them the same as the column names on top.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [IdeaSparks ASP.NET CoolControls](http://ideasparks.codeplex.com/wikipage?version=6)