# Scroll bar for Gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview, scrollbar

How to achieve scroll bar for gridview control in asp.net only for rows but not for header too.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to freeze GridView header?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157528/how-to-freeze-gridview-header)

Comment: You could use [IdeaSparks CoolGridView](http://johnsobrepena.blogspot.com/). It's opensource and works well.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

put the rows in div and add
"style=overflow:auto" in the div style
Above code will add scroll bars in the grid

Comment: op states the header should be left out of the scrolling area.

Comment: Check the answer, i wrote put only rows not headers, i am giving hint and logic.

Comment: putting a div around a `<tbody>` tag is not valid html.

Comment: why using <tbody> use <body> and sure this will work and render in any browser.

Comment: this is hopeless. the `<tbody>` wraps the rows in a proper accessible html table.  it is not proper html to place a div around the `<tbody>` tag inside of a table.

Comment: I have tested above code and it worked fine on Grid view with no issue :-).

Answer (score 0):

Just change this code as your own. You will get scroll when grid view size exit the div size.

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div style="height:200px; width:300px; overflow:auto;">
    <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
</body>
```