# How to make GridView scroll able vertically and have the Headers of the Grid Fixed

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I tried lot of code and browsed through many sites, but in vain. Can someone kindly help me with this issue.
I want `GridView` to be scrollable vertically and having its headers fixed. Hope the question is very clear.

I tried adding a  something like this:

```
<div style="overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x:visible; height: 100px;"> MY GRID </div>
```

Any ideas about css or in  kindly help.
Any small help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/157528/how-to-freeze-gridview-header

Answer (score 0):

i wrote jQuery plug-in can fixed header and freeze column, see the image:

[image: Demo Image]

look the website: http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/

Supported Browsers

- Internet Explorer 7, 8 (IE 9 Compatibility)
- Internet Explorer 9 (9.0.8112)
- Internet Explorer 10 on Windows 7 Preview
- Google Chrome(23.0.1271.64 m)
- Mozilla Firefox (16.0.2)
- Apple Safari (5.1.7)