# How to apply css overflow property on specific content

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am applying overflow property for `<form>`, in form i used `<legend>`. Here the overflow is applying to whole form so if overflow needed scroll bar includes legend also. but I want the overflow has to be applying except legend tag. I mean in form along with legend i used table . I want overflow has to be apply only for table.

here is my fiddle,

http://jsfiddle.net/raghavendram040/z6jRX/1/

my html is,

```
<form>
<fieldset>
<legend>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Menu</legend>
<table id="tab">
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>abc</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
```

my css is,

```
form{
  border: 1px #6A6A45 solid;
  border-radius:6px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color:#efefef ;
  margin-bottom: 17px;

}
```

to apply overflow I tried like this but it didnt worked

```
#tab{ overlow: auto }
```

How can I solve this can anyone help me in this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your table in a `div` and apply overflow to that.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/z6jRX/2/)

HTML

```
<form>
<fieldset>
    <legend>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Menu</legend>
    <div id="scroll">
        <table id="tab">
            <tr>
                <td>abc</td>
            </tr>
          ...
        </table>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

CSS

```
#scroll {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 140px;
}
```

Comment: Thank u . .it solved my pbm but I hav small problem, in another table i need to keep table header to be constant and need scroll bar to table rows. how to do that, pls help me.

Comment: There are many solutions :) [Here is a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019938/make-tbody-scrollable-in-webkit-browsers)

Comment: wer is the css for that table.

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap your table with a div element:

[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z6jRX/3/)

```
<div id="tab">
    <table>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u . .it solved my pbm but I hav small problem, in another table i need to keep table header to be constant and need scroll bar to table rows. how to do that, pls help me.

Comment: Ok.. update the fiddle above to illustrate your problem.