# Making divs behave like a table, without using display: table

Tags: html, css

[JSFiddle with the problem](http://jsfiddle.net/CjGL5/)

The headers should aline nicely with the content

Everything is allowed, just not using table elements

```
<div style="">
    <div style="">
        <span  class="" >Firstname</span>
        <span  class="" >Lastname</span>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="">
        <span class=""  style=""> Tom </span>
        <span class=""  style=""> Jones </span>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="">
        <span class=""  style=""> Micheal </span>
        <span class=""  style=""> Jackson </span>
    </div>
    <div style="" class="">
        <span class=""  style=""> SomedudewithsuperlongFirstname </span>
        <span class=""  style=""> SomedudewithsuperlongLastname </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The css:

```
   span{
        display: inline-block;
        min-width: 100px;
    }
    div div {
        min-width: 100px;
    }
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, this looks like tabular data so why not use tables?

Comment: I'd go ahead and just use tables, its tabular data anyways...But here you are -> http://jsfiddle.net/J83sG/

Comment: @JackWilliams you example doesn't take into automatic vertical height adjustments an html table will do.

Comment: That's true, but I think that's beyond the scope of what OP is looking for though, nevertheless, that's valid point.

Comment: I have just created a [new fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8aWL8/), this should behave even more like a table. If you want to support IE7 or under, you will need to use a [inline-block hack](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/cross-browser-inline-block/).

Comment: isn't there a newer, neater way? Tabular data... yes you are right, but I don't like tables, they behave very oddly and inconsistently with some things. Or am I wrong? IE7 is dead

Comment: @Toskan Why don't you like tables? If you explain, maybe we can clear up some misunderstandings. For this particular example, tables are the perfect, 100% fitting solution.

Comment: there seems to be many css properties that behave oddly or are not cross browser compatible. I had problems using rounded corners on tables a while back. Like everything behaves similar, but in table cells it is different.

Comment: @JackWilliams if u answer I will accept

Comment: @MrLister http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851760/firefox-4-no-longer-supports-scrollable-tbody-workarounds is a good example as well. Dafuq is this not in the html spec. In short, tables suck. End of story

Comment: @Toskan That does suck :-(

Comment: Pfff, just because they don't support fancy styling, they suck? Then you can also say SVG sucks because it doesn't support all styles. And underlining sucks because it is treated differently in different browsers. And HRs suck because they have different default styles in different browsers. And border-style:outset sucks because it causes different colors in different browsers. In short, you can just say that browsers suck and be done with it.

Comment: @MrLister a scrollable tbody aint that fancy. And yeah browsers suck, but they suck especially hard with certain elements.
But for the actual implementation, I went back to using tables together with jqueries datatables plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Prelude

Whilst you're right to be weary of using tables, if you use them to represent tabular data, that's fine!

But, as you rightly said, there are quite a few caveats of them; especially how certain browsers interpret them differently, as illustrated in your [Firefox 4 example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4851760/firefox-4-no-longer-supports-scrollable-tbody-workarounds) in the comments section.

Whilst i think some of the aforementioned issues could be overcome with CSS [table styles](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/), hacks and workarounds, i don't think it's worth the hassle or overhead.

### If you're not satisfied with HTML tables, or CSS table styles, we could emulate some `<table>` properties.

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="children">
        <p><span>Firstname</span></p>
        <p><span>Tom</span></p>     
        <p><span>SomedudewithsuperlongFirstname</span></p>     
    </div>
    <div class="children">
        <p><span>Lastname</span></p>
        <p><span>Jones</span></p>
        <p><span>SomedudewithsuperlongLastname</span></p>   
    </div>  
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
    display: block;
    border: 1px dashed #ccc;    
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.children{
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.children > p > span{
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/8aWL8/1/)

Comment: fix the firefox 4 link maybe

Comment: Done, sorry about that.

Comment: If you're going to abandon the semantic structure provided by tables (with headers) at least provide [`aria-labeledby`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-labelledby_attribute) attributes so that screenreader users will have a fighting chance to make sense of that.

Answer (score -1):

If you are looking for identical widths on your DIVs, min-width is probably not the way to go.  This only ensures the elements are a minimum width.  If the content in one "cell" exceeds this, they won't line up.

Maybe try *width* instead of *min-width*?  Or a larger *min-width*?