# <table><tbody> scrollable?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I would like to have a table with a scrollbar to the right.
I want to accomplish this without any plugins(jQuery) just with css.
The table header is supposed to stay fixed.

What do I need to do to get this working?

Comment: Please refer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130564/i-need-my-html-tables-body-to-scroll-and-its-head-to-stay-put

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You have taken on a task that, if you succeed, will make you a hero. I tried this and the straightforward thing -- to position:fixed; the <thead> -- is impossible. I had to copy all of the <thead> into a new object. But when you do that, the horizontal spacing of the <th> elements all goes away so the headings don't line up with the <td>s anymore. I ended up doing something like this:

First of all, abandon ie6 and ie7. There's no hope for those guys.

1. Make two copies of the table, one where the body is invisible and the <thead> is visible, and the other where it's vice-versa.
2. Give z-index:1; to the table with the visible <thead>.
3. Give z-index:0; to the table with the visible <tbody>.
4. Deal with horizontal scrolling, but not until after you find that onScroll isn't an ie8 event (not to mention ie6), so that you have to take a setInterval break every tenth of a second or so *just* to handle scrolling the <thead> left and right in ie8.

This will give you a table body of infinite scroll in both axes, with a table head that scrolls in the x axis only. Pretty much works in FF, Chrome, and Safari. But is shaky in ie8. A real pita.

Good luck, and please write if you get this to work!

Comment: I ended up using a second table and adding an additional <th></th> (empty) at the end of <table><theah><tr><th>One</th><th>Two</th><th></th></thead></table> and then setting it's width to 16 px so it lines up... Below that i have a second table... The header doesn't line up 100 % but it's good enought... :D

Comment: @JNK, good for you! And it's excellent that you can recognize the point at which it's "good enough," the point where, in practical terms, it's all finished.

Comment: Honestly this answer doesn't seem right. I get what you are saying, but even as illustrated in links below it is certainly possible. The trick is explicitly setting the height of the tbody instead of trying to let it inherit from a parent element. Potentially an ideal way around having to set the height of the tbody explicitly is simply creating a jQuery plugin that sets the height of the tbody to be the height of the container minus the height of the thead.

Comment: Thank's @PeteWilson. I have tried your solution and it's works on Firefox 24.0

Answer (score 5):

Only the Firefox and IE6-7 browsers support the built-in `<tbody>` scrolling:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
    <title>Scrolling</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        div.content
        {
            border: #000000 1px solid;
            height: 400px;
            overflow-y: auto;
            width: 800px;
        }

        .fixedHeader 
        {
            white-space: nowrap;
        }

        .fixedHeader tr 
        {
            height: auto;
            position: relative;
        }

        .fixedHeader tr td 
        {
            background-color: #778899;
            border: #000000 1px solid;
            text-align: center;
        }

        tbody.scrollContent 
        {
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;
            height: 370px;
        }

        .scrollContent tr td 
        {
            background-color: #C0C0C0;
            border: #000000 1px solid;
            padding-right: 22px;
            vertical-align: top;
        }
    </style>
    <!--[if IE]>
    <style type=text/css>
        div.content 
        {
            overflow-x: hidden;
            overflow-y: auto;
        }
    </style>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <div class="content">
        <table cellspacing="0">
            <thead class="fixedHeader">
                <tr>
                    <td>Cell 1</td>
                    <td>Cell 2</td>
                    <td>Cell 3</td>
                    <td>Cell 4</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody class="scrollContent">
                <tr>
                    <td>Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs. Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs. Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs.  Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs. Pages with tabs are preferred for a standard user interface, and pages without tabs are preferred for a wizard. If tabs are omitted, you must provide a way of moving through the pages. For instance, Back and Next buttons can be implemented. Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs. Pages with tabs are preferred for a standard user interface, and pages without tabs are preferred for a wizard. If tabs are omitted, you must provide a way of moving through the pages. For instance, Back and Next buttons can be implemented. Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs. Pages with tabs are preferred for a standard user interface, and pages without tabs are preferred for a wizard. If tabs are omitted, you must provide a way of moving through the pages. For instance, Back and Next buttons can be implemented.</td>
                    <td>Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs. Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs. </td>
                    <td>Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs. </td>
                    <td>Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs. Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs. Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs.  Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs. Pages with tabs are preferred for a standard user interface, and pages without tabs are preferred for a wizard. If tabs are omitted, you must provide a way of moving through the pages. For instance, Back and Next buttons can be implemented. Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs. Pages with tabs are preferred for a standard user interface, and pages without tabs are preferred for a wizard. If tabs are omitted, you must provide a way of moving through the pages. For instance, Back and Next buttons can be implemented. Pages can be displayed either with or without tabs. Pages with tabs are preferred for a standard user interface, and pages without tabs are preferred for a wizard. If tabs are omitted, you must provide a way of moving through the pages. For instance, Back and Next buttons can be implemented.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>            
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: IE doesn't support it at all. Webkit based browsers also not. Only FF2/3 and certain Operas did support it. The new FF4 will however [not](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Firefox_4_for_developers#Miscellaneous_CSS.c2.a0changes) support it anymore. This is namely not specified by W3.

Comment: The above is NOT a scrollable tbody with fixed header for ANY version of IE.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the solution,

Table fixed header and the content inside the table can be scrollable.

## HTML Part

```
<div class="table_wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="head1">Left</div>
        <div class="head2">Center</div>
        <div class="head3">Right Column</div>
    </div>
    <div class="tbody">
        <table>
            <tbody><tr><td class="td1">1</td><td class="td2">2</td><td class="td3">3</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="td1">1</td><td>2</td><td class="td3">3</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="td1">2</td><td>second</td><td class="td3">third</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="td1">3</td><td>second</td><td class="td3">third</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="td1">first</td><td>second</td><td class="td3">third</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="td1">first</td><td>second</td><td class="td3">third</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="td1">first</td><td>second</td><td class="td3">third</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="td1">first</td><td>second</td><td class="td3">third</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="td1">first</td><td>second</td><td class="td3">third</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="td1">first</td><td>second</td><td class="td3">third</td></tr>
            <tr><td class="td1">first</td><td>second</td><td class="td3">third</td></tr>
        </tbody></table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS Part**

```
.table_wrapper {background:tomato;border:1px double olive;float:left;}
.tbody{height:80px;overflow-y:auto;width:400px;background:yellow;}
table{border-collapse:collapse; width:100%;}
td{border-right:1px solid red;border-bottom:1px solid red;padding:1px 5px;}
.td3{border-right-width:0;}

.header{ width:400px;background:DodgerBlue;border-bottom:1px solid red;}
.header div{padding:1px 5px;float:left;border-right:1px solid orange;}
.header .head3{float:none;border-right-width:0;}
.head3 span{padding-left:5px;}

.td1{width:100px;}
.td2{width:140px;}
.header .head1{width:100px;}
.header .head2{width:140px;}
```

Comment: This works by giving up on automatically sizing column widths to content.

Answer (score 1):

This simple CSS should do the trick:

```
table.table-scroll-body {
  position: relative;
  height: 200px; }

  table.table-scroll-body tbody {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow: auto; }
```

And the HTML if you need it..

```
<table class="table-scroll-body">
  <thead>
    <th>Header 1</th>
    <th>Header 2</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Some content..</td>
      <td>Some content..</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some content..</td>
      <td>Some content..</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Some content..</td>
      <td>Some content..</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
```

Comment: the problem here to me is `<td>` width's, since they fit content and dont match `<thead>`. Good try though

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        table
        {
            width: 320px;
            display: block;
            border:solid black 1px;
        }

        thead
        {
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            height: 20px;
        }

        tbody
        {
            height: 200px;
            display: inline-block;
            width: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        th, td
        {
            width: 100px;
            text-align:center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Column 1</th>
                <th>Column 2</th>
                <th>Column 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Cell 1</td>
                <td>Cell 2</td>
                <td>Cell 3</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Worked great for me, and I am using bootstrap. I just prepended a class to each table attribute, wrapped table in div and this worked great. So this way I could call it only on specific div's and its child elements (the table elements).. I just removed the thead height, as it added an extra bar. otherwise great !!!

Answer (score 0):

branching off of astrandr's answer.. here is how I did it, using their example:

css:

```
 .transactHistory table
{
   width: 320px;
   display: block;
}

.transactHistory thead
{
  display: inline-block;
}

.transactHistory tbody
{
        height: 133px;
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: auto;
}

.transactHistory th
{
        width: 100px;
        text-align:center;
}

.transactHistory tr
{
        width: 100px;
        text-align:center;
 }

 .transactHistory td
 {
        width: 100px;
        text-align:center;
 }
```

Table:

```
 <div class="transactHistory">
    (..table code)
 </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

This works, took it right off my website:

```
#news_box {
overflow: scroll;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

EDIT: 
I also just found this with a nice example:
http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Here's another good article on it:
http://www.scientificpsychic.com/blogentries/html-and-css-scrolling-table-with-fixed-heading.html

Comment: but on those two pages the entire table -- including the thead -- scrolls right off the page. Yes, if you scroll the table body only it works great. But if the table is real, real deep and real, real wide, I'd like to use the page scrollbar while keeping the header visible at the top all the time. Just imo, of course.

Comment: try to open this one on ie7 or ie8 it would be a miracle if it works from there. :)