# Fixed GridView Header with horizontal and vertical scrolling in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I want to fix(Freeze) gridview header while vertical scrolling.

I also want to fix first column while horizontal scrolling.

I want this in both chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer Here which is 100% working

https://stackoverflow.com/a/59357398/11863405

Static Header for Gridview Control

Comment: This does not seem to work if you have things like "AllowSorting" set to true or if you have added other postback functionality to the header.  If you have sorting enabled for instance, and you click on the header column to sort, the entire gridview disappears.

Answer (score 5):

It is possible to apply the specific GridView / Table layout via custom CSS rules (as it was discussed in the [<table><tbody> scrollable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345390/tabletbody-scrollable/5345479#5345479) thread) to fix GridView's Header. However, this approach will not work in all browsers. [The 3-rd ASP.NET GridView controls (such as the ASPxGridView from DevExpress component vendor](http://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxGridViewDemos/PagingAndScrolling/Scrolling.aspx) provide this functionality.

Check also the following CodeProject solutions:

- [Fixed header Grid](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/FixedHeaderGrid.aspx)
- [Gridview with fixed header](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/webforms/GridViewwithfixedhead.aspx)
- [Gridview Fixed Header](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/Gridview_Fixed_Header.aspx)

Comment: None of these solutions works as expected. All of them rely on fixed-width columns and either separate header from rest of the table or use IE-specific top:expression(...) which does not work on any other browser.

btw. Articles in CodeProject should be considered wrong by default. My experience so far is, that if you find an article only on  codeproject and nowhere else - it's either wrong or bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for a solution for this for a long time and found most of the answers are not working or not suitable for my situation i also find most of the java script code for that they worked but only with the vertical scroll not with the horizontal scroll and also combination of header and rows doesn't match.

Finally i have found a solution with javascript here is the link bellow :-

[**scrollable horizontal and vertical grid view with fixed headers**](http://www.dotnetbull.com/2011/11/scrollable-gridview-with-fixed-headers.html)

Comment: This does not seem to work if you have things like "AllowSorting" set to true or if you have added other postback functionality to the header.  If you have sorting enabled for instance, and you click on the header column to sort, the entire gridview disappears.

Answer (score 0):

You can try `overflow` css property.

Answer (score 0):

```
// create this Js and add reference

var GridViewScrollOptions = /** @class */ (function () {
    function GridViewScrollOptions() {
    }
    return GridViewScrollOptions;
}());

var GridViewScroll = /** @class */ (function ()
 {

    function GridViewScroll(options) {
        this._initialized = false;
        if (options.elementID == null)
            options.elementID = "";
        if (options.width == null)
            options.width = "700";
        if (options.height == null)
            options.height = "350";
        if (options.freezeColumnCssClass == null)
            options.freezeColumnCssClass = "";
        if (options.freezeFooterCssClass == null)
            options.freezeFooterCssClass = "";
        if (options.freezeHeaderRowCount == null)
            options.freezeHeaderRowCount = 1;
        if (options.freezeColumnCount == null)
            options.freezeColumnCount = 1;
        this.initializeOptions(options);
    }
    GridViewScroll.prototype.initializeOptions = function (options) {
        this.GridID = options.elementID;
        this.GridWidth = options.width;
        this.GridHeight = options.height;
        this.FreezeColumn = options.freezeColumn;
        this.FreezeFooter = options.freezeFooter;
        this.FreezeColumnCssClass = options.freezeColumnCssClass;
        this.FreezeFooterCssClass = options.freezeFooterCssClass;
        this.FreezeHeaderRowCount = options.freezeHeaderRowCount;
        this.FreezeColumnCount = options.freezeColumnCount;
    };

    GridViewScroll.prototype.enhance = function () 
{

        this.FreezeCellWidths = [];
        this.IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled = false;
        this.IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled = false;
        if (this.GridID == null || this.GridID == "")
 {

            return;
        }

        this.ContentGrid = document.getElementById(this.GridID);
        if (this.ContentGrid == null) {

            return;
        }
        if (this.ContentGrid.rows.length < 2) {


            return;
        }
        if (this._initialized) {

            this.undo();
        }

        this._initialized = true;
        this.Parent = this.ContentGrid.parentNode;
        this.ContentGrid.style.display = "none";
        if (typeof this.GridWidth == 'string' && this.GridWidth.indexOf("%") > -1) {
            var percentage = parseInt(this.GridWidth);
            this.Width = this.Parent.offsetWidth * percentage / 100;
        }
        else {

            this.Width = parseInt(this.GridWidth);
        }
        if (typeof this.GridHeight == 'string' && this.GridHeight.indexOf("%") > -1) {


            var percentage = parseInt(this.GridHeight);
            this.Height = this.Parent.offsetHeight * percentage / 100;
        }
        else {

            this.Height = parseInt(this.GridHeight);
        }

        this.ContentGrid.style.display = "";
        this.ContentGridHeaderRows = this.getGridHeaderRows();
        this.ContentGridItemRow = this.ContentGrid.rows.item(this.FreezeHeaderRowCount);
        var footerIndex = this.ContentGrid.rows.length - 1;
        this.ContentGridFooterRow = this.ContentGrid.rows.item(footerIndex);
        this.Content = document.createElement('div');
        this.Content.id = this.GridID + "_Content";
        this.Content.style.position = "relative";
        this.Content = this.Parent.insertBefore(this.Content, this.ContentGrid);
        this.ContentFixed = document.createElement('div');
        this.ContentFixed.id = this.GridID + "_Content_Fixed";
        this.ContentFixed.style.overflow = "auto";
        this.ContentFixed = this.Content.appendChild(this.ContentFixed);
        this.ContentGrid = this.ContentFixed.appendChild(this.ContentGrid);
        this.ContentFixed.style.width = String(this.Width) + "px";
        if (this.ContentGrid.offsetWidth > this.Width) {

            this.IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled = true;
        }

        if (this.ContentGrid.offsetHeight > this.Height) {

            this.IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled = true;
        }

        this.Header = document.createElement('div');
        this.Header.id = this.GridID + "_Header";
        this.Header.style.backgroundColor = "#F0F0F0";
        this.Header.style.position = "relative";
        this.HeaderFixed = document.createElement('div');
        this.HeaderFixed.id = this.GridID + "_Header_Fixed";
        this.HeaderFixed.style.overflow = "hidden";
        this.Header = this.Parent.insertBefore(this.Header, this.Content);
        this.HeaderFixed = this.Header.appendChild(this.HeaderFixed);
        this.ScrollbarWidth = this.getScrollbarWidth();
        this.prepareHeader();
        this.calculateHeader();
        this.Header.style.width = String(this.Width) + "px";
        if (this.IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled) {

            this.HeaderFixed.style.width = String(this.Width - this.ScrollbarWidth) + "px";
            if (this.IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled) {

                this.ContentFixed.style.width = this.HeaderFixed.style.width;
                if (this.isRTL()) {

                    this.ContentFixed.style.paddingLeft = String(this.ScrollbarWidth) + "px";
                }

                else {

                    this.ContentFixed.style.paddingRight = String(this.ScrollbarWidth) + "px";
                }

            }

            this.ContentFixed.style.height = String(this.Height - this.Header.offsetHeight) + "px";
        }

        else {

            this.HeaderFixed.style.width = this.Header.style.width;
            this.ContentFixed.style.width = this.Header.style.width;
        }

        if (this.FreezeColumn && this.IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled) {

            this.appendFreezeHeader();
            this.appendFreezeContent();
        }
        if (this.FreezeFooter && this.IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled) {

            this.appendFreezeFooter();
            if (this.FreezeColumn && this.IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled) {


                this.appendFreezeFooterColumn();
            }
        }
        var self = this;
        this.ContentFixed.onscroll = function (event) {

            self.HeaderFixed.scrollLeft = self.ContentFixed.scrollLeft;
            if (self.ContentFreeze != null)
                self.ContentFreeze.scrollTop = self.ContentFixed.scrollTop;
            if (self.FooterFreeze != null)
                self.FooterFreeze.scrollLeft = self.ContentFixed.scrollLeft;
        };
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.getGridHeaderRows = function () {



        var gridHeaderRows = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.FreezeHeaderRowCount; i++) {

            gridHeaderRows.push(this.ContentGrid.rows.item(i));

        }
        return gridHeaderRows;
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.prepareHeader = function () {

        this.HeaderGrid = this.ContentGrid.cloneNode(false);
        this.HeaderGrid.id = this.GridID + "_Header_Fixed_Grid";
        this.HeaderGrid = this.HeaderFixed.appendChild(this.HeaderGrid);
        this.prepareHeaderGridRows();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.length; i++) {

            this.appendHelperElement(this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.item(i));
            this.appendHelperElement(this.HeaderGridHeaderCells[i]);
        }
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.prepareHeaderGridRows = function () {

        this.HeaderGridHeaderRows = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.FreezeHeaderRowCount; i++) {
            var gridHeaderRow = this.ContentGridHeaderRows[i];
            var headerGridHeaderRow = gridHeaderRow.cloneNode(true);
            this.HeaderGridHeaderRows.push(headerGridHeaderRow);
            this.HeaderGrid.appendChild(headerGridHeaderRow);
        }

        this.prepareHeaderGridCells();
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.prepareHeaderGridCells = function () {

        this.HeaderGridHeaderCells = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.length; i++) {

            for (var rowIndex in this.HeaderGridHeaderRows) {


                var cgridHeaderRow = this.HeaderGridHeaderRows[rowIndex];
                var fixedCellIndex = 0;
                for (var cellIndex = 0; cellIndex < cgridHeaderRow.cells.length; cellIndex++) {
                    var cgridHeaderCell = cgridHeaderRow.cells.item(cellIndex);
                    if (cgridHeaderCell.colSpan == 1 && i == fixedCellIndex) {

                        this.HeaderGridHeaderCells.push(cgridHeaderCell);
                    }
                    else {
                        fixedCellIndex += cgridHeaderCell.colSpan - 1;
                    }
                    fixedCellIndex++;
                }
            }
        }
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.calculateHeader = function () {

        for (var i = 0; i < this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.length; i++) {

            var gridItemCell = this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.item(i);
            var helperElement = gridItemCell.firstChild;
            var helperWidth = parseInt(String(helperElement.offsetWidth));
            this.FreezeCellWidths.push(helperWidth);
            helperElement.style.width = helperWidth + "px";
            helperElement = this.HeaderGridHeaderCells[i].firstChild;
            helperElement.style.width = helperWidth + "px";
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < this.FreezeHeaderRowCount; i++) {

            this.ContentGridHeaderRows[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.appendFreezeHeader = function () {

        this.HeaderFreeze = document.createElement('div');
        this.HeaderFreeze.id = this.GridID + "_Header_Freeze";
        this.HeaderFreeze.style.position = "absolute";
        this.HeaderFreeze.style.overflow = "hidden";
        this.HeaderFreeze.style.top = "0px";
        this.HeaderFreeze.style.left = "0px";
        this.HeaderFreeze.style.width = "";
        this.HeaderFreezeGrid = this.HeaderGrid.cloneNode(false);
        this.HeaderFreezeGrid.id = this.GridID + "_Header_Freeze_Grid";
        this.HeaderFreezeGrid = this.HeaderFreeze.appendChild(this.HeaderFreezeGrid);
        this.HeaderFreezeGridHeaderRows = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < this.HeaderGridHeaderRows.length; i++) {

            var headerFreezeGridHeaderRow = this.HeaderGridHeaderRows[i].cloneNode(false);
            this.HeaderFreezeGridHeaderRows.push(headerFreezeGridHeaderRow);
            var columnIndex = 0;
            var columnCount = 0;
            while (columnCount < this.FreezeColumnCount) {

                var freezeColumn = this.HeaderGridHeaderRows[i].cells.item(columnIndex).cloneNode(true);
                headerFreezeGridHeaderRow.appendChild(freezeColumn);
                columnCount += freezeColumn.colSpan;
                columnIndex++;
            }
            this.HeaderFreezeGrid.appendChild(headerFreezeGridHeaderRow);
        }
        this.HeaderFreeze = this.Header.appendChild(this.HeaderFreeze);
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.appendFreezeContent = function () {

        this.ContentFreeze = document.createElement('div');
        this.ContentFreeze.id = this.GridID + "_Content_Freeze";
        this.ContentFreeze.style.position = "absolute";
        this.ContentFreeze.style.overflow = "hidden";
        this.ContentFreeze.style.top = "0px";
        this.ContentFreeze.style.left = "0px";
        this.ContentFreeze.style.width = "";
        this.ContentFreezeGrid = this.HeaderGrid.cloneNode(false);
        this.ContentFreezeGrid.id = this.GridID + "_Content_Freeze_Grid";
        this.ContentFreezeGrid = this.ContentFreeze.appendChild(this.ContentFreezeGrid);
        var freezeCellHeights = [];
        var paddingTop = this.getPaddingTop(this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.item(0));
        var paddingBottom = this.getPaddingBottom(this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.item(0));
        for (var i = 0; i < this.ContentGrid.rows.length; i++) {

            var gridItemRow = this.ContentGrid.rows.item(i);
            var gridItemCell = gridItemRow.cells.item(0);
            var helperElement = void 0;
            if (gridItemCell.firstChild.className == "gridViewScrollHelper") {

                helperElement = gridItemCell.firstChild;
            }
            else {
                helperElement = this.appendHelperElement(gridItemCell);
            }
            var helperHeight = parseInt(String(gridItemCell.offsetHeight - paddingTop - paddingBottom));
            freezeCellHeights.push(helperHeight);
            var cgridItemRow = gridItemRow.cloneNode(false);
            var cgridItemCell = gridItemCell.cloneNode(true);
            if (this.FreezeColumnCssClass != null || this.FreezeColumnCssClass != "")
                cgridItemRow.className = this.FreezeColumnCssClass;
            var columnIndex = 0;
            var columnCount = 0;
            while (columnCount < this.FreezeColumnCount) {

                var freezeColumn = gridItemRow.cells.item(columnIndex).cloneNode(true);
                cgridItemRow.appendChild(freezeColumn);
                columnCount += freezeColumn.colSpan;
                columnIndex++;
            }
            this.ContentFreezeGrid.appendChild(cgridItemRow);
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < this.ContentGrid.rows.length; i++) {

            var gridItemRow = this.ContentGrid.rows.item(i);
            var gridItemCell = gridItemRow.cells.item(0);
            var cgridItemRow = this.ContentFreezeGrid.rows.item(i);
            var cgridItemCell = cgridItemRow.cells.item(0);
            var helperElement = gridItemCell.firstChild;
            helperElement.style.height = String(freezeCellHeights[i]) + "px";
            helperElement = cgridItemCell.firstChild;
            helperElement.style.height = String(freezeCellHeights[i]) + "px";
        }
        if (this.IsVerticalScrollbarEnabled) {
            this.ContentFreeze.style.height = String(this.Height - this.Header.offsetHeight - this.ScrollbarWidth) + "px";
        }
        else {
            this.ContentFreeze.style.height = String(this.ContentFixed.offsetHeight - this.ScrollbarWidth) + "px";
        }
        this.ContentFreeze = this.Content.appendChild(this.ContentFreeze);
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.appendFreezeFooter = function () {

        this.FooterFreeze = document.createElement('div');
        this.FooterFreeze.id = this.GridID + "_Footer_Freeze";
        this.FooterFreeze.style.position = "absolute";
        this.FooterFreeze.style.overflow = "hidden";
        this.FooterFreeze.style.left = "0px";
        this.FooterFreeze.style.width = String(this.ContentFixed.offsetWidth - this.ScrollbarWidth) + "px";
        this.FooterFreezeGrid = this.HeaderGrid.cloneNode(false);
        this.FooterFreezeGrid.id = this.GridID + "_Footer_Freeze_Grid";
        this.FooterFreezeGrid = this.FooterFreeze.appendChild(this.FooterFreezeGrid);
        this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow = this.ContentGridFooterRow.cloneNode(true);
        if (this.FreezeFooterCssClass != null || this.FreezeFooterCssClass != "")
            this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow.className = this.FreezeFooterCssClass;
        for (var i = 0; i < this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow.cells.length; i++) {

            var cgridHeaderCell = this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow.cells.item(i);
            var helperElement = this.appendHelperElement(cgridHeaderCell);
            helperElement.style.width = String(this.FreezeCellWidths[i]) + "px";
        }
        this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow = this.FooterFreezeGrid.appendChild(this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow);
        this.FooterFreeze = this.Content.appendChild(this.FooterFreeze);
        var footerFreezeTop = this.ContentFixed.offsetHeight - this.FooterFreeze.offsetHeight;
        if (this.IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled) {

            footerFreezeTop -= this.ScrollbarWidth;
        }
        this.FooterFreeze.style.top = String(footerFreezeTop) + "px";
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.appendFreezeFooterColumn = function () {

        this.FooterFreezeColumn = document.createElement('div');
        this.FooterFreezeColumn.id = this.GridID + "_Footer_FreezeColumn";
        this.FooterFreezeColumn.style.position = "absolute";
        this.FooterFreezeColumn.style.overflow = "hidden";
        this.FooterFreezeColumn.style.left = "0px";
        this.FooterFreezeColumn.style.width = "";
        this.FooterFreezeColumnGrid = this.HeaderGrid.cloneNode(false);
        this.FooterFreezeColumnGrid.id = this.GridID + "_Footer_FreezeColumn_Grid";
        this.FooterFreezeColumnGrid = this.FooterFreezeColumn.appendChild(this.FooterFreezeColumnGrid);
        this.FooterFreezeColumnGridHeaderRow = this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow.cloneNode(false);
        this.FooterFreezeColumnGridHeaderRow = this.FooterFreezeColumnGrid.appendChild(this.FooterFreezeColumnGridHeaderRow);
        if (this.FreezeFooterCssClass != null)
            this.FooterFreezeColumnGridHeaderRow.className = this.FreezeFooterCssClass;
        var columnIndex = 0;
        var columnCount = 0;
        while (columnCount < this.FreezeColumnCount) {

            var freezeColumn = this.FooterFreezeGridHeaderRow.cells.item(columnIndex).cloneNode(true);
            this.FooterFreezeColumnGridHeaderRow.appendChild(freezeColumn);
            columnCount += freezeColumn.colSpan;
            columnIndex++;
        }
        var footerFreezeTop = this.ContentFixed.offsetHeight - this.FooterFreeze.offsetHeight;
        if (this.IsHorizontalScrollbarEnabled) {

            footerFreezeTop -= this.ScrollbarWidth;
        }
        this.FooterFreezeColumn.style.top = String(footerFreezeTop) + "px";
        this.FooterFreezeColumn = this.Content.appendChild(this.FooterFreezeColumn);
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.appendHelperElement = function (gridItemCell) {

        var helperElement = document.createElement('div');
        helperElement.className = "gridViewScrollHelper";
        while (gridItemCell.hasChildNodes()) {

            helperElement.appendChild(gridItemCell.firstChild);
        }
        return gridItemCell.appendChild(helperElement);
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.getScrollbarWidth = function () {

        var innerElement = document.createElement('p');
        innerElement.style.width = "100%";
        innerElement.style.height = "200px";
        var outerElement = document.createElement('div');
        outerElement.style.position = "absolute";
        outerElement.style.top = "0px";
        outerElement.style.left = "0px";
        outerElement.style.visibility = "hidden";
        outerElement.style.width = "200px";
        outerElement.style.height = "150px";
        outerElement.style.overflow = "hidden";
        outerElement.appendChild(innerElement);
        document.body.appendChild(outerElement);
        var innerElementWidth = innerElement.offsetWidth;
        outerElement.style.overflow = 'scroll';
        var outerElementWidth = innerElement.offsetWidth;
        if (innerElementWidth === outerElementWidth)
            outerElementWidth = outerElement.clientWidth;
        document.body.removeChild(outerElement);
        return innerElementWidth - outerElementWidth;
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.isRTL = function () {

        var direction = "";
        if (window.getComputedStyle) {

            direction = window.getComputedStyle(this.ContentGrid, null).getPropertyValue('direction');
        }
        else {
            direction = this.ContentGrid.currentStyle.direction;
        }
        return direction === "rtl";
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.getPaddingTop = function (element) {

        var value = "";
        if (window.getComputedStyle) {

            value = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('padding-Top');
        }
        else {

            value = element.currentStyle.paddingTop;
        }
        return parseInt(value);
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.getPaddingBottom = function (element) {
        var value = "";

        if (window.getComputedStyle) {

            value = window.getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('padding-Bottom');
        }
        else {

            value = element.currentStyle.paddingBottom;
        }
        return parseInt(value);
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.undo = function () {

        this.undoHelperElement();
        for (var _i = 0, _a = this.ContentGridHeaderRows; _i < _a.length; _i++) {
            var contentGridHeaderRow = _a[_i];
            contentGridHeaderRow.style.display = "";
        }
        this.Parent.insertBefore(this.ContentGrid, this.Header);
        this.Parent.removeChild(this.Header);
        this.Parent.removeChild(this.Content);
        this._initialized = false;
    };
    GridViewScroll.prototype.undoHelperElement = function () {

        for (var i = 0; i < this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.length; i++) {

            var gridItemCell = this.ContentGridItemRow.cells.item(i);
            var helperElement = gridItemCell.firstChild;
            while (helperElement.hasChildNodes()) {

                gridItemCell.appendChild(helperElement.firstChild);
            }
            gridItemCell.removeChild(helperElement);
        }
        if (this.FreezeColumn) {

            for (var i = 2; i < this.ContentGrid.rows.length; i++) {

                var gridItemRow = this.ContentGrid.rows.item(i);
                var gridItemCell = gridItemRow.cells.item(0);
                var helperElement = gridItemCell.firstChild;
                while (helperElement.hasChildNodes()) {


                    gridItemCell.appendChild(helperElement.firstChild);
                }
                gridItemCell.removeChild(helperElement);
            }
        }
    };
    return GridViewScroll;
}());

//add On Head

<head runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="client/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

    <script src="js/gridviewscroll.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {

            var gridViewScroll = new GridViewScroll({
                elementID: "GridView1" // [Header is fix column will be Freeze ][1]Target Control
            });
            gridViewScroll.enhance();
        }
    </script>

</head>

//Add on Body

<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">

       // <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

           <%-- <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="SHIPMENT_ID" HeaderText="SHIPMENT_ID"
                    ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="SHIPMENT_ID" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="TypeValue" HeaderText="TypeValue"
                    SortExpression="TypeValue" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="CHAId" HeaderText="CHAId"
                    SortExpression="CHAId" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Status" HeaderText="Status"
                    SortExpression="Status" />
            </Columns>--%>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            var gridHeader = $('#<%=grdSiteWiseEmpAttendance.ClientID%>').clone(true); // Here Clone Copy of Gridview with style
            $(gridHeader).find("tr:gt(0)").remove(); // Here remove all rows except first row (header row)
            $('#<%=grdSiteWiseEmpAttendance.ClientID%> tr th').each(function (i) {
                // Here Set Width of each th from gridview to new table(clone table) th 
                $("th:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")", gridHeader).css('width', ($(this).width()).toString() + "px");
            });
            $("#GHead1").append(gridHeader);
            $('#GHead1').css('position', 'top');
            $('#GHead1').css('top', $('#<%=grdSiteWiseEmpAttendance.ClientID%>').offset().top);

        });
    </script>

<div class="row">
                                                        <div class="col-lg-12" style="width: auto;">
                                                            <div id="GHead1"></div>
                                                            <div id="divGridViewScroll1" style="height: 600px; overflow: auto">
                                                                <div class="table-responsive">
                                                                    <asp:GridView ID="grdSiteWiseEmpAttendance" CssClass="table table-small-font table-bordered table-striped" Font-Size="Smaller" EmptyDataRowStyle-ForeColor="#cc0000" HeaderStyle-Font-Size="8" HeaderStyle-Font-Names="Calibri" HeaderStyle-Font-Italic="true" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
                                                                        BackColor="#f0f5f5" OnRowDataBound="grdSiteWiseEmpAttendance_RowDataBound" HeaderStyle-ForeColor="#990000">

                                                                        <Columns>
                                                                        </Columns>
                                                                        <HeaderStyle HorizontalAlign="Justify" VerticalAlign="Top" />
                                                                        <RowStyle Font-Names="Calibri" ForeColor="#000000" />
                                                                    </asp:GridView>
                                                                </div>
                                                            </div>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
```

Comment: This does not seem to work if you have things like "AllowSorting" set to true or if you have added other postback functionality to the header.  If you have sorting enabled for instance, and you click on the header column to sort, the entire gridview disappears.  Would love to know a solution to that issue because your solution is very simple and clean.

Answer (score 0):

***Acheived by using java script...***

**Copy and paste given below javascript code inside the head tag.**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
         function MakeStaticHeader(gridId, height, width, headerHeight, isFooter) {
         var tbl = document.getElementById(gridId);
         if (tbl) {
         var DivHR = document.getElementById('DivHeaderRow');
         var DivMC = document.getElementById('DivMainContent');
         var DivFR = document.getElementById('DivFooterRow');
        
         //*** Set divheaderRow Properties ****
         DivHR.style.height = headerHeight + 'px';
         DivHR.style.width = (parseInt(width) - 16) + 'px';
         DivHR.style.position = 'relative';
         DivHR.style.top = '0px';
         DivHR.style.zIndex = '10';
         DivHR.style.verticalAlign = 'top';
        
         //*** Set divMainContent Properties ****
         DivMC.style.width = width + 'px';
         DivMC.style.height = height + 'px';
         DivMC.style.position = 'relative';
         DivMC.style.top = -headerHeight + 'px';
         DivMC.style.zIndex = '1';
        
         //*** Set divFooterRow Properties ****
         DivFR.style.width = (parseInt(width) - 16) + 'px';
         DivFR.style.position = 'relative';
         DivFR.style.top = -headerHeight + 'px';
         DivFR.style.verticalAlign = 'top';
         DivFR.style.paddingtop = '2px';
        
         if (isFooter) {
         var tblfr = tbl.cloneNode(true);
         tblfr.removeChild(tblfr.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0]);
         var tblBody = document.createElement('tbody');
         tblfr.style.width = '100%';
         tblfr.cellSpacing = "0";
         tblfr.border = "0px";
          tblfr.rules = "none";
         //*****In the case of Footer Row *******
         tblBody.appendChild(tbl.rows[tbl.rows.length - 1]);
         tblfr.appendChild(tblBody);
         DivFR.appendChild(tblfr);
         }
         //****
         DivHR.appendChild(tbl.cloneNode(true));
         }
        }
        
        
        
        function OnScrollDiv(Scrollablediv) {
          document.getElementById('DivHeaderRow').scrollLeft = Scrollablediv.scrollLeft;
        document.getElementById('DivFooterRow').scrollLeft = Scrollablediv.scrollLeft;
        }
        
    </script>
```

**Then Copy this code and paste and place your Grid View inside DivMainContent.**

**HTML Code:-**

```
    <div id="DivRoot" align="left">
    
       <div style="overflow: hidden;" id="DivHeaderRow">
       </div>
        
       <div style="overflow:scroll;" onscroll="OnScrollDiv(this)" id="DivMainContent">
               
       <%--  ***Place Your GridView Here***
       <asp:GridView  runat="server"  ID="gridshow" Width="100%" 
       AutoGenerateColumns="False"ShowFooter="True">
          <Columns>
             //...................
          </Columns>
       </asp:GridView>
       --%>
              
       </div>
        
          <div id="DivFooterRow" style="overflow:hidden">
          </div>
    </div>
```

**Then Call function MakeStaticHeader in Aspx.CS File at the time of binding Gridview and pass the Some parameters.**

1. ClientId of Gridview(Change GrdDisplay.ClientID as your gridview clientid).
2. Height of Scrollable div.
3. Width of Scrollable div.
4. Height of Table Header Row.
5. IsFooter (true/false) If you want to Make footer static or not.

**-->After binding the Gridview, place below code**

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, this.GetType(), "Key", "<script>MakeStaticHeader('" + GrdDisplay.ClientID + "', 400, 950 , 40 ,true); </script>", false);
```

[image: Demo]

**Hope this will work for sure...**