# Columns not matching between thead and tbody

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an application here: [Application](http://helios.hud.ac.uk/u0867587/Mobile_app/QandATable3.php)

In the application please do the following:

1. You will see a green plus button on left hand side, click on it and it will open up a modal window.
2. In the search bar in the modal window type in the phrase `single` and submit search. A table will be shown below.
3. Add a row from the table by clicking on the "Add" button, it will add the information in the top controls.
4. Finally click on the "Add Question" button, this will append a table row underneath.

Now the issue I have is that the columns in the `<thead>` and the columns in the `<tbody>` does not match. What my question is that how can I get these columns to match?

HTML code is below showing the appended rows:

```
    var $tbody = $('#qandatbl > tbody'); 
    var $tr = $("<tr class='optionAndAnswer' align='center'>");
    var $td = $("<td class='extratd'>");
    var $plusrow = $("<td class='plusrow'></td>");
    var $qid = $("<td class='qid'></td>").text(qnum);
    var $question = $("<td class='question'></td>");
    var $noofanswers = $("<div class='noofanswers'>2. Number of Answers:<br/></div>");
    var $options = $("<div class='option'>1. Option Type:<br/></div>");
    var $answer = $("<div class='answer'>3. Answer:<br/></div>");
    var $replies = $("<td class='noofreplies'><div class='wrapper'></div></td>");
    var $weight = $("<td class='weight'></td>");
    var $image = $("<td class='image'></td>"); 
    var $video = $("<td class='video'></td>");
    var $audio = $("<td class='audio'></td>");

...

    $tr.append($plusrow);
    $tr.append($qid);
    $tr.append($question);
    $tr.append($td);
    $td.append($options);
    $td.append($noofanswers);
    $td.append($answer);
    $tr.append($replies);
    $tr.append($weight);   
    $tr.append($image);  
    $tr.append($video);
    $tr.append($audio);
    $tbody.append($tr);
```

Below is the html table where it contains the table headings columns and where the table rows are appended to:

```
<table id="qandatbl" align="center">
<thead class="tblhead">
<tr>
    <th></th>
    <th class="qid">Question No</th>
    <th class="question">Question</th>
    <th class="optandans">Option and Answer</th>
    <th class="noofreplies">Number of Replies</th>
    <th class="weight">Number of Marks</th>
    <th class="image">Image</th>
    <th class="video">Video</th>
    <th class="audio">Audio</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="tblbody">
</tbody>
</table>
```

Finally below is the CSS Code:

```
body{
    font-size:85%;  
}           

#qandatbl{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

#qandatbl td { 
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#qandatbl th{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;
}

.tblhead, .tblbody {
    display: block;
}

.tblbody{
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    width:100%; 
}

.extratd{
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.qid { 
    min-width:3%;
    max-width:3%;
    font-weight:bold;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.question { 
    min-width:25%;
    max-width:25%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.noofanswers{
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
}

.noofreplies{
    min-width:3%;
    max-width:3%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.optandans{
    min-width:30%;
    max-width:30%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.option{
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
}

.weight { 
    min-width:3%;
    max-width:3%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    }

.answer { 
    min-width:100%;
    max-width:100%;
    padding-top:5%;
    padding-bottom:5%;
     }

.audio{
    min-width:11%;
    max-width:11%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    }

.video{
    min-width:11%;
    max-width:11%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    }

.image{
    min-width:11%;
    max-width:11%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    position:relative;
    }

.plusrow{
    min-width:2%;
    max-width:2%;
    border:1px black solid;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    }
```

I have included a jsfiddle so you can look at a demo of it and test any ideas you have: http://jsfiddle.net/heA2b/1/

Comment: green button doesnt work

Comment: Just get a php error and button does nothing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first answer (user1721135) is incorrect, it's because you've assigned the thead and tbody a display of "block".  Remove that and your problem will disappear.

He is right that you don't have to assign a mix and a max-width if they are the same, but that's not what is causing your issue.

Edit to add working example: http://codepen.io/joe/pen/gqzbf

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer, but the reason I needed the "block" for thead and tbody is because I want the table to scroll with fix headers. Can I ask then that if I need to "remove" block to keep columns matching, then how can I display a scrolling table with fixed headers with columns matching? I have marked your answer, this is just a question I am asking for a favour if you don't mind and have time and idea

Comment: There's a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345390/tabletbody-scrollable that covers it.  It doesn't look simple, sadly.