# Can I use <div> tag inside a table

Tags: html, html-table

I have requirement, that needs table rows inside a table excluding head row scrollable.
 I have tried as follows, but this does not give the desired result:

```
 <table id="applicantList1" border="1" align="left">
<tr><td align="center" colspan="4"><b>Select one record from the below list for proceeding further </b></td></tr>
<tr><th>View</th><th>Name</th><th>Address</th><th>Pan No</th></tr>
  <c:forEach items="${applicantList}" var = "applicantList">  
    <div id="applicantList2" align="center" style="height:1px;width: 10px">
    <tr>
        <td>${applicantList[0]}</td>
        <td>${applicantList[1]}</td>
        <td>${applicantList[2]},${applicantList[3]},${applicantList[4]},${applicantList[5]},${applicantList[6]},${applicantList[7]}</td>
        <td>${applicantList[8]}</td>
      </tr> 
    </div>                
  </c:forEach> 
</table>
```

If any one have an idea, please share with me.

Comment: check out: http://www.imaputz.com/cssStuff/bigFourVersion.html

Comment: YOu can always check your html here http://htmledit.squarefree.com/

Comment: @Ismet, it doesn't work in IE

Comment: @jammykam you're right. tested it with IE8 and it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you able to use JavaScript? jQuery? What browsers do you need to support?

A CSS only solution is not possible, welcome to the holy grail:
[<table><tbody> scrollable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345390/tabletbody-scrollable)

You can try this as a CSS only solution, but the scrolling will not work in IE. You need to add `thead` and `tbody` tags to your table markup:
http://tjvantoll.com/2012/11/10/creating-cross-browser-scrollable-tbody/

So your only solution for 100% coverage is to use JavaScript. I would use a combination of the above and a plugin so it degrades nicely when JS is off. [DataTables is a jQuery plugin](http://www.datatables.net/) I've used before, if you need a pure JavsScript plugin, I'm sure you can Google them...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid scrolling the header I would try to create a structure consisting of two aligned tables. One for the header and a second table for the body. That way you can ensure that only the second table scrolls

If you're open to third party solutions I would also recommend the Telerik grids since they all support this behavior

Answer (score 0):

Not the way you're using it.
Use a list instead of forcing a tr inside a div.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using css:

You could place your table inside a `<div>` with it's position set to relative. Inside the `<div>` set the table to inherit the position attribute. Set the  in the table to `position: absolute` and `top: 0`, and the rest of the elements in the table should have their positions set to `inherit`.