# Bootstrap 3 Floating Table Headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a simple application that displays a table based on selected features and companies a user wants to compare. I am using Bootstrap 3 but because of the way my code works, I cannot use DataTables. I want the table header to float, and I have tried quite a few methods to get this to work. This includes JavaScript/JQuery/CSS solutions on the table header and JS/CSS solutions on tbody scrolling.

One problem is that my code destroys and rebuilds the table every time a user changes their selections. I am pretty new to Web development and this is the only thing so far that has really given me issues. I would really appreciate any help! Thanks in advance!

Link to working version: http://www.buyvm.theoks.net/b-rant/EHR_Tool/EHR_Form.php

Comment: Show us your code before you get down voted.

Comment: What exactly would you like to see? It is all in the page, you can see it by viewing source.

Comment: Thank captain. What you linked is a working version. Why would I want to see that ? Even if I look at the source, how will I know the difference between your code and actually say "hey this is where you are wrong" ... I am (was) interested in the problem aka your code.

Comment: This does not have a floating table header implemented yet, I am asking if people have ideas to help me get a working floating header or scrolling tbody.

Comment: Everything I have tried so far has not worked for various reasons.

Answer (score 1):

Floating headers / scrolling tbody is just not viable in HTML right now. It seems the best you can do is have two tables: the first for the headers, and the second for the body wrapped in a `<div style=overflow: auto;></div>` and hope the columns line up.

[<table><tbody> scrollable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5345390/tabletbody-scrollable)

[How can I let a table's body scroll but keep its head fixed in place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130564/i-need-my-html-tables-body-to-scroll-and-its-head-to-stay-put)