# Keep table header (<thead> tag) constant

Tags: html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I need my html table's body to scroll and its head to stay put](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130564/i-need-my-html-tables-body-to-scroll-and-its-head-to-stay-put)

I got a table and want the headers between  tag to stay constant on the screen while rest is scrollable. How can I accomplish this? I tried to use a iframe, no luck.

Comment: Did you try `position: fixed`?

Comment: @Inkbug When `position:fixed` is used, the cells are not aligned properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below mentioned link

http://encolpe.wordpress.com/2008/05/01/how-to-add-a-fixed-table-header-with-a-vertical-scrollbar-in-content/

This will give you the idea to create fix header in table