# Adding scroll bars to 2 tables

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-table, autoscroll

I am trying to display  2 individual scroll bars for 2 tables wrapped inside a div.

My code is as follows

```
<html>
<body>



<div style="width:300px;background:#00CC33;height:100px;">
<div style="width:150px;float:left;">
<table width="100px" border="1">
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
<div style="width:100px;float:left;">
<table width="100px" border="1">
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>

</table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

What I tried: I tried to use overflow:scroll; but when I am doing so both the tables are getting wrapped in one scroll bar.

Above mentioned tables are dynamically generated.
demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HLyDq/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following Styles to the two table-parent divs:

```
<div style="...;overflow-y:auto;max-height:100px;">
```

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gQyYe/

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the **height:100px** and the **overflow:auto** styles to the DIV which is the immediate parent of each Table.

Here is the corrected code

```
    <html>
<body>



**<div style="width:300px;background:#00CC33;height:100px;">
<div style="width:150px;float:left;height:100px;overflow:auto;">**
<table width="100px" border="1">
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr><tr>
  <td>100</td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
**<div style="width:100px;float:left;height:100px;overflow:auto;">**
<table width="100px" border="1">
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>100</td>
  <td>200</td>
  <td>300</td>
</tr>

</table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The code enclosed between a pair of ** are the corrected lines. Check this JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/yYxuN/1/

Hope this helps

Comment: yup. Your solution works. I  am wondering why background color of outermost div is lost in your solution

Answer (score 0):

there's an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130564/i-need-my-html-tables-body-to-scroll-and-its-head-to-stay-put) that can be helpful - I hope.
I'd prefer `overflow:auto;`in any case