# Table tbody scroll in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

In my project, I am trying to make the `tbody` scroll in IE8. I know it can be scrolled by just giving `overflow: auto` to `tbody`. But this doesn't work in IE8. To make it work in IE8, the `tbody` must be given `position: absolute` (or `float: left` to both `thead` and `tbody`). If I make the `overflow: auto` work then the widths which I assigned to the `th` and `td` in percentages is being ignored. which in turn not letting the `tr` to occupy the full width in `thead` and `tbody`. Hence, there is a irritating space between `tr` and `tbody`/`thead`.

Please test this [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/X8FSw/3/embedded/result/) in IE8. (*works fine in firefox and chrome*)

and here is the code in [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/X8FSw/3/).

Here are the strict points which I can't change

- Width to `td` and `th` must be in percentages.
- I can't change HTML markup
- It must be solved using just CSS.

Actually, I did solve it with a dirty fix which is as follows

```css
th:after,td:after{ /* only to the last column, first occurence */
    content: "...................................................";
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

*The above code can also be checked by giving many dots to a specific td/th in developer tools*

The above code looks ok but I need to give the `:after` pseudo selector only to the first row last column `th` and `tr`. If I give to every `th` and `tr` then the layout is messing up. and also the `dots` must be increased if the empty space between the `tr` and `tbody` is more. Then ofcourse this could be achieved only dynamically which I can't do in my current project.

PS: *I maybe doing it completely wrong. I am just sharing my efforts where I reached very close to the result*.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found two ways to solve this problem in IE8.

**1)**   Adding extra `td` element of `width: 0px` to `tr`'s of thead and tbody.

[IE8 demo](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/X8FSw/17/show/)

**2)**   Adding a hidden letter to content of `after` pseudo selector.

```
    tr:after{
        content: ".";
        visibility: hidden;
    }
```

I added the above in conditional css. because the problem was only in IE8. (*I haven't tested in IE9+*)

```
    <!--[if IE 8]>
         <style>
             /* the above css code here */
         </style>
    <![endif]-->
```

[IE8 demo](http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/X8FSw/18/show/)

I used the latter one because it is simple.

Comment: This is brilliant... most solutions require JavaScript or non-semantic markup. Thank you kind sir.