# How to add horizontall scroll to the table not the page with the fixed header using css?

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I want to add the scroll bar to the table instead of page ,Now scrollbar is taking to tbody or page with fixed header. how to give the scrollbar to the `table` rather than `tbody` or `page` . as i am giving the scroll to `tbody`.  Is it possible to give the scrollbar to table with fixed header.
in this below example i have the scroll in `page`, or i can add in tbody. how to add the scroll bar for table with fixed header using css.[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/g73dyvm2/4/) Can anyone please help me. It is not the duplicate of [adding scrollbar to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584702/how-to-add-a-scrollbar-to-an-html5-table) .because if i have more columns in to table. the overflowed columns are not showing in this example

Comment: @TeutaKoraqi that horizontal scroll bar is there for page or document, not for the table. i want the scroll bar to the table

Comment: @Matthias it is not the duplicate, because try adding more columns and check, i am trying like to have the scrollbar to the table. i don't want to hide the overflowed columns