# Fix table header while scrolling

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html-table

I'm using React, trying to create a table with the header fixed on screen while the body scrolls.

I have checked [many solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584702/how-to-add-a-scrollbar-to-an-html5-table) but they do not satisfy my requirements below:

1. the table must remain print friendly (all rows in the table must be printable)
2. the column width must not be fixed (it should be based on width of col content)

This solution satisfies point 2 but not 1: https://jsfiddle.net/flytrap/g2cxd0jj/

```
/* this is for the main container of the table, also sets the height of the fixed header row */
.headercontainer {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid #222;
  padding-top: 37px;
  background: #000;
}
/* this is for the data area that is scrollable */
.tablecontainer {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 200px;
  background: #fff;
}

/* remove default cell borders and ensures table width 100% of its container*/
.tablecontainer table {
  border-spacing: 0;
}

/* add a thin border to the left of cells, but not the first */
.tablecontainer td + td {
  border-left:1px solid #eee; 
}

/* cell padding and bottom border */
.tablecontainer td, th {
  border-bottom:1px solid #eee;
  padding: 10px;
}

/* make the default header height 0 and make text invisible */
.tablecontainer th {
    height: 0px;
    padding-top: 0;
    padding-bottom: 0;
    line-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* reposition the divs in the header cells and place in the blank area of the headercontainer */
.tablecontainer th div{
  visibility: visible;
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 9px 10px;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
  line-height: normal;
   border-left: 1px solid #222;
}
/* prevent the left border from above appearing in first div header */
th:first-child div{
  border: none;
}

/* alternate colors for rows */
.tablecontainer tbody  tr:nth-child(even){
     background-color: #ddd;
}
```

Comment: Please add your current relevant code.

Comment: @I haz kode added current code and link to jsfiddle

Comment: @Avery235 why not use some plugin like JQuery Datatables?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try this code**

use `translate` to make header fixed

```
document.getElementById("table-container").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
  var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
  this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;

});
```

to print
all rows in the table add this in css

```
   @media print {
       #table-container{
         height:100%;
       }
   }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ab2tq6ck/show/)

**updation**

---

update css with below to avoid mess up printing after scrolling

```
@media print {
       #table-container{
         height:100%;
       }
       #table-container thead{
         transform: none!important;
       }
   }
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/ab2tq6ck/4/show/)

Comment: This solution would require me to include JQuery in my React project?

Comment: Just strongly discouraged by React. Pure CSS/HTML/React solution is much preferred.

Comment: scrolling the table will mess up the printing. any trick to reset it to top before print?

Comment: Thanks so much for the help so far! Just have one last problem: http://i.imgur.com/AdaBTa1.png as soon as i start scrolling, the th borders disappeared, and when i scroll back to the top, only partial border is shown: http://i.imgur.com/ez71b6l.png. Been trying to isolate the problem for an hour without luck. My CSS is very similar to yours and the project is proprietary so I'm not able to show the source. Any clue what might possibly be wrong?

Comment: Hi found the issue,adding `border-spacing: 0;` to table will fix this problrm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151033/discussion-between-avery235-and-amal).

Comment: This was a great idea! I can't believe I didn't think of this immediately.

Will be implementing this in React. Thanks!