# Table with fixed header in IE8

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8

I need some help. I tried for 2 days to make a table with tbody scrollable and I just can't find a solution.

My table is:

```
<table width=100% style="margin:0 0 0 -1px; border-collapse:collapse;"> 

<thead>
    <tr>        
        <th ><input type="checkbox" id="select_all" /></th> 
        <c:forEach items="${grid.heads}" var="element">  
             <th><c:out value="${element.id}"/></th>           
        </c:forEach>  
    </tr>   
</thead>

<tbody style="height:200px !important;   overflow: auto; display:block;">       
  <nested:iterate id="row" name="grid" property="data" indexId="cnt">                                                                
       <tr> 
         <td><input type="checkbox" name="list_with_checkboxes" value=<c:out value="${row[0]}"/> ></td>
             <nested:iterate id="element" name="row">  
                      <td><c:out value="${element}"/> </td>
            </nested:iterate>
       </tr>
  </nested:iterate>        
</tbody>    

</table>
```

My table is rendered correctly but I can't make tbody scrollable, because I don't know why tbody have another height then 200px.

Any ideas? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be lots of answers to this already

[Table tbody scroll in IE8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16984323/table-tbody-scroll-in-ie8)

[How can I let a table's body scroll but keep its head fixed in place?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/130564/i-need-my-html-tables-body-to-scroll-and-its-head-to-stay-put)

```
<th style="width:0px;"></th>
```

This existing fiddle seems to solve it but check out the other suggestions in the links above- http://jsfiddle.net/venkateshwar/X8FSw/17/show/

Comment: I read all the answers but nothing helped me. The main idea is how to make a tbody scrollable. I will take a look at your links also. Thanks!

Comment: Look at the source of the fiddle. There is an extra row with a width of 0 added in to help it in IE8. Might be worth copying source and styles and modifying to suit your needs.

Answer (score 1):

how about you make 2 tables, the first table only contains the thead

```
    <table>
    <thead>
 <th>HEADER</th>
    </thead>
    </table>

    <div style="height:200px !important; overflow:scroll;">
    <table>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: I can't do that because table is generated dynamic and the header it will not be aligned with body. I already tried that.