# html css tr set width

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the HTML table & its CSS.

CSS :

```
#outerDIV {
  position: relative;
  padding-top: 20px;
}
#innerDIV {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 500px;
}
table#mytable tbody tr:first-child 
{
    width:100%;
    position :absolute;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="outerDIV">
  <div class="innerDIV">
    <table id="#mytable"></table>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need the fixed header tags of table, so is the above code does, but the width of the th tags gets compressed to the left & does not matches the width of the `tr's` of the body. How to make the tr to 100% width ?

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16984323/1577396)

Comment: Provided code is not correct. there is no table with specified ID.

Comment: Have tried removing `position:absolute`?

Comment: I want first tr i.e. th tags to be fixed. So, cannot remove it.

Comment: Maybe you don't need to use `tr` then. Maybe `div` would work better.

Comment: I cannt remove th's because it gets the width of the other td's & align in the same position. If i use div, then it will mis-aligned

Answer (score 0):

You want the `<th>` to span the width of multiple columns, but you can't do this with CSS so you need to do it in the HTML (see [HTML colspan in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403990/html-colspan-in-css)).

If you add a `colspan` attribute to the `<th>` it should do what you want (see [Colspan all columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398734/colspan-all-columns)). If you know the number of columns in the table, use that, e.g. for 5 columns use `<th colspan="5">`, but you can also use a larger number and it should be ok, e.g. `<th colspan="100">`.

Some other notes: as others have mentioned, you shouldn't use `position` on a `<tr>`. Also, don't include the `#` in an element `id`, i.e. it should be

```
<table id="mytable"></table>
```

Answer (score 0):

NEVER try to use absolute or even relative re-positioning on `<tr>`, `<td>` and `<th>`. It's not supposed to work in tables, and in most cases the results will be nowhere near what you'd expect.